# Emgu CV draw rotated rectangle

Tags: rotation, draw, shapes, emgucv, angle

I'm looking for few days a solution to draw rectangle on image frame. Basically I'm using `CvInvoke.cvRectangle` method to draw rectangle on image because I need antialiased rect.
But problem is when I need to rotate a given shape for given angle. I can't find any good solution. 
I have tryed to draw rectangle on separate frame then rotate hole frame and apply this new image on top of my base frame. But in this solution there is a problem with antialiasing. It's not working.
I'm working on simple application that should allow draw few kinds of shape, resize them and rotation for given angle. 
Any idea how to achive this?

Answer (score 2):

The best way I found to draw a minimum enclosing rectangle on the contour is using the [Polylines()](https://emgu.com/wiki/files/3.0.0/document/html/d53da061-2902-be71-8125-ebefd769fe9f.htm) function which uses vertices that are returned from [MinAreaRect()](https://emgu.com/wiki/files/3.0.0/document/html/f07ccdec-de3f-8333-7ca6-7c4a6c319040.htm) function. There are surely other ways to do it as well. Here is the code walk down:

```
// Find contours
var contours = new Emgu.CV.Util.VectorOfVectorOfPoint();
Mat hierarchy = new Mat();
CvInvoke.FindContours(image, contours, hierarchy, RetrType.Tree, ChainApproxMethod.ChainApproxSimple);

// According to your metric, get an index of the contour you want to find the min enclosing rectangle for
int index = 2; // Say, 2nd index works for you.
var rectangle = CvInvoke.MinAreaRect(contours[index]);
Point[] vertices = Array.ConvertAll(rectangle.GetVertices(), Point.Round);
CvInvoke.Polylines(image, vertices, true, new MCvScalar(0, 0, 255), 5);
```

The result can be visualized in the image below, in red is the minimum enclosing rectangle.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I use C# and EMGU.CV(4.1), and I think this code will not be difficult to transfer to any platform.

Add function in the in your helper:

```
public static Mat DrawRect(Mat input, RotatedRect rect, MCvScalar color = default(MCvScalar),
        int thickness = 1, LineType lineType = LineType.EightConnected, int shift = 0)
{
    var v = rect.GetVertices();

    var prevPoint = v[0];
    var firstPoint = prevPoint;
    var nextPoint = prevPoint;
    var lastPoint = nextPoint;


    for (var i = 1; i < v.Length; i++)
    {
        nextPoint = v[i];
        CvInvoke.Line(input, Point.Round(prevPoint), Point.Round(nextPoint), color, thickness, lineType, shift);
        prevPoint = nextPoint;
        lastPoint = prevPoint;
    }
    CvInvoke.Line(input, Point.Round(lastPoint), Point.Round(firstPoint), color, thickness, lineType, shift);
    return input;
}
```

This draws roteted rectangle by points. Here used rounding points by method `Point.Round` becose `RotatedRect` has points in float coordinates and `CvInvoke.Line` takes points as integer.

Use:

```
    var mat = Mat.Zeros(200, 200, DepthType.Cv8U, 3);
    mat.GetValueRange();
    var rRect = new RotatedRect(new PointF(100, 100), new SizeF(100, 50), 30);
    DrawRect(mat, rRect,new MCvScalar(255,0,0));
    var brect = CvInvoke.BoundingRectangle(new VectorOfPointF(rRect.GetVertices()));
    CvInvoke.Rectangle(mat, brect, new MCvScalar(0,255,0), 1,  LineType.EightConnected, 0);
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score -2):

You should read the [OpenCV documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html).

There is a `RotatedRectangle` class that you can use for your task. You can specify the angle by which the rectangle will be rotated.

Here is a sample code (taken from the docs) for drawing a rotated rectangle:

```
Mat image(200, 200, CV_8UC3, Scalar(0));
RotatedRect rRect = RotatedRect(Point2f(100,100), Size2f(100,50), 30);

Point2f vertices[4];
rRect.points(vertices);
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    line(image, vertices[i], vertices[(i+1)%4], Scalar(0,255,0));

Rect brect = rRect.boundingRect();
rectangle(image, brect, Scalar(255,0,0));

imshow("rectangles", image);
waitKey(0);
```

Here is the result:

[image: rotated rectnagle]

Comment: Point2f is not a proper type for CvInvoke.Line(). Therefore the answer is wrong.